# How to move a URL for a ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting, url-routing

My SEO colleague has fired in a few url requests that involve moving

www.mydomain.co.uk/news 
www.mydomain.co.uk/news/{id}/{title}

to

www.mydomain.co.uk/uk-news
www.mydomain.co.uk/uk-news/{id}/{title}

What is the best way to carry this out.

I was just thinking of changing the route in the global.asax file

FROM:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
      "News", // Route name
      "News", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "News", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

TO:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "News", // Route name
  "uk-news", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "News", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and setting up a 301 redirect on the basic www.mydomain.co.uk/news

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. Your on the right track, changing the URL on the route and doing the 301 permanent redirect is the way to go. For the 301 try using the URL Rewrite Module.

**Rewrite Module**

```
<!-- Web.config file in subdirectory to be redirected -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.old-domain\.com" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**ISAPI_Rewrite**

```
RewriteCond Host: ^mydomain\.co.uk
RewriteRule /news http://www.mydomain.co.uk/uk-news [I,O,RP,L]
```

I (ignore case)

Indicates that characters are matched regardless of a case. This flag affects RewriteHeader directive and all corresponding RewriteCond directives.

O (nOrmalize)

Normalizes string before processing. Normalization includes removing of an URL-encoding, illegal characters, etc. Also, IIS normalization of an URI completely removes query string. So, normalization should not be used if query string is needed. This flag is useful with URLs and URL-encoded headers.

RP (permanent redirect)

Almost the same as the [R] flag but issues 301 (moved permanently) HTTP status code instead of 302 (moved temporary).

L (last rule)

Stop the rewriting process here and don't apply any more rewriting rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am just wondering if the rewrite module would work on IIS 6?

Comment: Aww nope. I use isapi_rewrite for our iis 6 instances :/ you can check it out but it's not free, what is free is http://iirf.codeplex.com/ give it a try.

Comment: I have a ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file, what would the rewrite condition be? sorry i an not familiar with ISAPI_rewrite